# Modifiers (SHIFT + (Random Key)) in Key Binding

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, modifiers, modifier-key

How can I alter the Input/Action map so when I bind an action to a specific key it also binds an action to *Some Modifier* + specific key?

i.e. `SHIFT_DOWN_MASK + specific key`

So all of my key bindings work without modifiers.  I am assigning a sound file to a certain letter on the key board and when I press that key, the sounds file plays.  I also have code to loop the sound file, toggle whether or not it loops, and check if it loops.  I want to have it so that, in addition to binding the `play()` action to the key, it will bind the `toggleLoop()` action to the action `SHIFT_DOWN_MASK + specific key`.

Where I bind actions:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public void bindKey(JPanel base)
    {
        base.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key),"play"+key);
        base.getActionMap().put("play"+key, new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println(key + " Pressed");
                play();

            }
        });

        //assigning action just the key pressed

        base.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char)(key-32), InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),"loop"+(char)(key-32));
        base.getActionMap().put("loop"+(char)(key-32), new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println(key + " toggled loop");
                toggleLoop();
                //fix toggle

            }
        });

        //^ where I try to assign action to modifier



    }
```

Comment: share only the related-question part of your code ... not all the class :)

Comment: +1 to ALJI Mohamed. Please [read this](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Fixed it, and solved my problem anyways.  I'll post how I solved it for anyone else looking.

Comment: @Alex can you please post your answer as as answer instead of at the bottom of the question?

Comment: Use the virtual key values from `KeyEvent` over absolute numerical values, this will prevent issues if the assignments ever change

Answer (score 1):

> FIXED: Changed to (char)(key-32) so it would assign it to the
>   lowercase character, because it was setting 'W' instead of 'w' when I
>   used the shift modifier.

Comment: @Alex hmm .. thinking in terms of lower/uppercase is a bit off scope in keyBindings: it's always a-single-key plus (optionally) a-modifier. How/if that combination would map to a keyChar is irrelevant. So, if this is the "solution" something in the setup smells fishy :-) Were/how do you get the _key_ ?

Comment: @kleopatra I am getting the keys from the last button I clicked's get text.  so keyboardBtns[i].getText().charAt(0), it may not be very efficient but I am just trying to get a working prototype that I can go back and make more efficient/more logical.